# How can execute all of the Ranking STRUCTURE. USING recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

```
CREATE DATABASE TASKPERFORMANCE1

USE TASKPERFORMANCE1

DROP TABLE Students

CREATE TABLE Students 
(
     ID VARCHAR(99), 
     Name VARCHAR(99), 
     LeaderID VARCHAR(99)
)

INSERT INTO Students (ID, Name, LeaderID) 
VALUES (100, 'Baldo', null),
       (101, 'Cardo', 101),
       (102, 'Pedro', 101),
       (103, 'Luningning', 101),
       (104, 'Paolo', 102),
       (105, 'Roberto', 102),
       (106, 'Narciso', 102),
       (107, 'Jopay', 102),
       (108, 'Bernardo', 103),
       (109, 'Policarpio', 103),
       (110, 'Sisa', 103),
       (111, 'Reginaldo', 104)
 
;WITH RankingStructure (LeaderID,ID,Name,Ranking) AS
(
    SELECT LeaderID, ID, Name, 0 AS Ranking
    FROM Students
    WHERE LeaderID IS NULL

    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT S.LeaderID, S.ID, S.Name, R.Ranking + 1
    FROM Students S
    INNER JOIN RankingStructure R ON R.ID = S.LeaderID
)
SELECT LeaderID, ID, Name, Ranking
FROM RankingStructure
```

Comment: When i execute the codes for recursive the output is only 1 line.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or SQLite? How is S involved?

Comment: Seems like a data error - nobody declares 100/Baldo to be their leader.

Comment: `(101, 'Cardo', 101),` How can one person also be the "leader" of the same person? Your recursion attempt fails because no one is "under" Baldo. I.E., Baldo leads no one and your recursion attempt starts with that row.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Sorry i'm newbie in ms sql. how can fix my problem?

Comment: No one can "fix" your problem without understanding your schema, how it is designed, and what your actual goal is. Perhaps Cardo should also be a "leader" - designated by setting LeaderId to NULL for that row? A search for a tutorial using something like "sql server recursive cte hierarchy" as your search term might be a good start.